# Weird Behavior when using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am writing a wrapper to Eigen for my personal use and I encountered the following weird behavior:

```
void get_QR(MatrixXd A, MatrixXd& Q, MatrixXd& R) {
        HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A);
        Q  =   qr.householderQ()*(MatrixXd::Identity(A.rows(),A.cols()));
        R  =   qr.matrixQR().block(0,0,A.cols(),A.cols()).triangularView<Upper>();
}

void get_QR(double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R) {
        //      Maps the double to MatrixXd.
        Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);

        //      Obtains the QR of A_E.
        MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
        get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

        //      Maps the MatrixXd to double.
        Q       =       Q_E.data();
        R       =       R_E.data();
}
```

Below is the test:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int m   =       atoi(argv[1]);
    int n   =       atoi(argv[2]);

    //      Check the double version.

    double* A       =       new double[m*n];
    double* Q;
    double* R;

    double RANDMAX  =       double(RAND_MAX);

    //      Initialize A as a random matrix.

    for (int index=0; index<m*n; ++index) {
            A[index]        =       rand()/RANDMAX;
    }

    get_QR(A, m, n, Q, R);
    std::cout << Q[0] << std::endl;

    //      Check the MatrixXd version.

    Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);
    MatrixXd Q_E(m,n), R_E(n,n);
    get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);
    std::cout << Q[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I get different values of Q[0]. For instance, I get "-0.421857" and "-1.49563".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer of George is correct but suffers from unnecessary copies. A better solution consists in mapping Q and R:

```
void get_QR(const double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R) {
    Map<const MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);
    Map<MatrixXd> Q_E(Q, m, n);
    Map<MatrixXd> R_E(Q, n, n);

    HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A_E);
    Q_E = qr.householderQ()*(MatrixXd::Identity(m,n));
    R_E = qr.matrixQR().block(0,0,n,n).triangularView<Upper>();
}
```

In order to be able to reuse the `get_QR` function taking Eigen's object, then use `Ref<MatrixXd>` instead of `MatrixXd`:

```
void get_QR(Ref<const MatrixXd> A, Ref<MatrixXd> Q, Ref<MatrixXd> R) {
    HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A);
    Q = qr.householderQ()*(MatrixXd::Identity(A.rows(),A.cols()));
    R = qr.matrixQR().block(0,0,A.cols(),A.cols()).triangularView<Upper>();
}

void get_QR(const double* A, int m, int n, double* Q, double* R) {
    Map<const MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);
    Map<MatrixXd> Q_E(Q, m, n);
    Map<MatrixXd> R_E(R, n, n);
    get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);
}
```

The `Ref<MatrixXd>` can wrap any Eigen's object that is similar to a `MatrixXd` without any copy. This include `MatrixXd` itself, as well as `Map` and `Block` expressions. This requires Eigen 3.2.

Comment: Thanks and good to see you here. Is there a way I can avoid copies and call the other function `get_QR(MatrixXd A, MatrixXd& Q, MatrixXd& R)` instead of rewriting this code? (Currently, this is what I have, but seems to be unnecessary code repetition).

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner if you find answers helpful, feel free to click the up arrow. Also, my advice would be to get the code to work first, and then worry about optimizations. The memcpy() would require least amount of changes (and is the closest to what you intended), that's why it's there.

Comment: @ggael Thanks. `Ref<const MatrixXd>` is very useful. `Ref` is it part of Eigen or C++?

Comment: @ggael Also, do you visit stackoverflow often? If so, I can ask my Eigen questions here instead of the KDE forum, since this has a better interface than the KDE forums.

Comment: @ggael I tried your modification. However, there is a problem. It looks like the rows and columns of `Q` and `R` need to be specified apriori, which I do not want, when calling `get_QR(Ref<const MatrixXd> A, Ref<MatrixXd> Q, Ref<MatrixXd> R)` directly. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Ref is an Eigen thing. I fixed a copy/paste typo in the get_QR taking Ref<> objects. Sizes do not have to be fixed at compile-time, the above code should really work.

Comment: @ggael If I call the function `get_QR(Ref<const MatrixXd> A, Ref<MatrixXd> Q, Ref<MatrixXd> R)`, from outside, where I declare `Q` and `R` as `MatrixXd Q`, `MatrixXd R`, I get the following error: `Assertion failed: (rows() == other.rows() && cols() == other.cols()), function lazyAssign, file /usr/local/include/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h, line 498.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with Eigen.

It looks like you are assigning pointer Q to a memory location belonging to a local variable Q_E

```
        Q       =       Q_E.data();
```

which leaks the previous memory allocation

```
double* Q       =       new double[m*n];
```

and is meaningless or undefined outside of the `get_QR()` function.

You should use memcpy instead:

```
memcpy(Q, Q_E.data(), m*n*sizeof(double));
```