# Is there any memory issue with the way I handled this?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am writing a wrapper to Eigen QR for my personal use and I am wondering if there is any memory leak or undocumented behavior in my implementation especially in the function `void get_QR(double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R)`. The answer is as expected. This is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103526/weird-behavior-when-using-eigen).

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace Eigen;

/*!
 Obtains the QR decomposition as A=QR, where all the matrices are in Eigen MatrixXd format.
 */
void get_QR(MatrixXd A, MatrixXd& Q, MatrixXd& R) {

        int m           =       A.rows();
        int n           =       A.cols();
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);

        //      A_E     =       Q_E*R_E.
        HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A);
        Q  =   qr.householderQ()*(MatrixXd::Identity(m, minmn));
        R  =   qr.matrixQR().block(0, 0, minmn, n).triangularView<Upper>();
}

/*!
 Obtains the QR decomposition as A=QR, where all the matrices are in double format.
 */
void get_QR(double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R) {
        MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);

        //      Maps the double to MatrixXd.
        Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);

        get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

        Q       =       (double*)realloc(Q_E.data(), m*minmn*sizeof(double));
        R       =       (double*)realloc(R_E.data(), minmn*n*sizeof(double));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        srand(time(NULL));

        int m   =       atoi(argv[1]);
        int n   =       atoi(argv[2]);

//      Check the double version.
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);
        double* A       =       (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
        double* Q       =       (double*)malloc(m*minmn*sizeof(double));
        double* R       =       (double*)malloc(minmn*n*sizeof(double));

        double RANDMAX  =       double(RAND_MAX);
        //      Initialize A as a random matrix.
        for (int index=0; index<m*n; ++index) {
                A[index]        =       rand()/RANDMAX;
        }

        get_QR(A, m, n, Q, R);
        std::cout << Q[0] << std::endl;

//      Check the MatrixXd version.
        Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);
        MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
        get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

        cout << Q[0] << endl;
        cout << Q_E(0,0) << endl;

        free(A);
        free(Q);
        free(R);
}
```

For instance, I get the output as

```
-0.360995
-0.360995
-0.360995
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could run it through valgrind to check if there is any error reported.

Comment: @timrau I am on Maverick and valgrind doesn't work on Maverick.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719762/are-there-any-alternatives-to-valgrind-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-and-mavericks-t then.

Comment: @timrau Yes, I did and I get the same error as Jonathan has posted. `configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x and 11.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7)`

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` is not guaranteed to be compatible with `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`, only with `malloc` and `free`.

I would just replace all your `double*` pointers with `std::vector<double>` objects.

Comment: However there is placement new

Comment: Yes, right. I have got ride of the `new` now and replaced with `malloc`. I do not want to use `vector`. If so, is my implementation, leak free and undocumented behavior free.

Comment: `I do not want to use vector`  Why not?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because this will be used by other codes and those rely purely on double* to denote array or matrices.

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner - a vector is compatible with an array by specifying the address of the first element.  So I see no reason why you can't use vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, that would be useful, though could you elaborate on it. For instance, if a user passes an array to a function, how would I use a `vector` without copying the array contents (i.e., just by manipulating the memory of the first element)? Thanks.

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner - Yes.  A vector basically takes what you did and puts it into a class.  That's basically all it does.  All you need to learn is how to get into the internals of this class, and taking the address of the first element is the way to do it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. For instance, if I have a pointer `a` how should I put it in a vector? Can you add that one line of code? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you also answer my original question, as to if my code is right or has some memory leaks or UB? Thanks again and sorry to bug you repeatedly.

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner - See my answer.  Your original code does not check if malloc() or realloc() returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your calls to malloc and free with a vector.  Here is sample code of how you would use vector with existing code that takes a pointer to double.

```
#include <vector>
//...
void foo(double* d, int size)
{
   d[0] = 10;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<double> d(10);  // 10 doubles
   foo(&d[0], d.size());
}
```

The foo() function is an "old C" function that expects a pointer to double to denote a double array.  Note that to do this magic, you pass the address of the first element.

So your original code could look like this, given the above:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<double> VectDouble;

void get_QR(VectDouble& A, int m, int n, VectDouble& Q, VectDouble& R) 
{
    MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
    int minmn       =       min(m,n);

    //      Maps the double to MatrixXd.
    Map<MatrixXd> A_E(&A[0], m, n);

    get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

    Q.resize(m * minmn);
    R.resize(minmn *n, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int m   =       atoi(argv[1]);
    int n   =       atoi(argv[2]);

    int minmn       =       min(m,n);
    VectDouble A(m*n);
    VectDouble Q(m*minmn);
    VectDouble R(minmn*n);

    double RANDMAX  =       double(RAND_MAX);
    //      Initialize A as a random matrix.
    std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), rand()/RANDMAX);

    get_QR(A, m, n, Q, R);
    std::cout << Q[0] << std::endl;

    Map<MatrixXd> A_E(&A[0], m, n);
    MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
    get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

    cout << Q[0] << endl;
    cout << Q_E(0,0) << endl;
}
```